# Django + Bootstrap navbar button and search field issue

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5

I know that there are similar questions, but I tried and searched hard and didn't find a solution for my problem. I am using Django + bootstrap to complete an exercise which include a navbar. The search button is stubbornly staying below the search field.

[image: As in the picture]

I would just like to align them, as in this example :

[image]

Here my code :

'''

```
      </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>


            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 col-3">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </nav>
```

'''

Don't know if it's a naive issue, but I am really struggling and loosing time with it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `form-control` class in the search input enforces a `display: block;`.

There are several solutions, depending of your needs: you can make the input inline, you can use [flexbox behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) by adding the `d-flex` class to your form, or you can do something like that:

```
<form class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

(btw, you can read the [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) about gutters if necessary)

Finally, please think about giving a runnable code snippet in your future questions :)